# Pulling Wordpress titles with PHP code and formatting with strtok

Tags: php, wordpress, strtok

I am trying to create a list of keywords for a search autocomplete by using the titles of Wordpress posts and separating the individual words as "keywords" using strtok. I can't quite figure out how to add the "the_title" php tag into the string. I have tried multiple options but my basic PHP is lacking. Let me know if there's a way to accomplish this.

```
<script>
let words = [
    "Example1",
    "Example2"

 <?php $documents = new Wp_Query(['post_type'=>'documents']); 
    if ($documents->have_posts()) : 
    while ($documents->have_posts()) : $documents->the_post(); ?>
 <?php
    $string = '<?php the_title() ?>';
    $delim = ' \– \-,.!?:;';
    $tok = strtok($string, $delim);
    while ($tok !== false) {
        echo "\"$tok\", ";
        $tok = strtok($delim);
    }
    ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    "ExampleBottom1",
    "ExampleBottom2"
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Three pieces of observations:

1. The Wordpress function [the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) does not return the title.  Instead it print things out as a side effect. It is also faulty to use `<?php` within another `<?php` scope. You should use [get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) instead.
2. Also, directly printing string as javascript would have problem if there are any quotes in them. You need to sanitize the string.

I think the simpler way is to format the whole javascript array with PHP then print it out. The function [json_encode()](https://php.net/json_encode) will do all necessary sanitation and quoting for you before printing out `$words` as javascript array:

```php
<?php

$words = [
    'Example1',
    'Example2',
];

$query = new \WP_Query(['post_type'=>'documents']); 
$delim = ' \– \-,.!?:;';
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $tok = strtok(get_the_title(), $delim);
    while ($tok !== false) {
        $words[] = $tok;
        $tok = strtok($delim);
    }
}

array_push($words, [
    'ExampleBottom1',
    'ExampleBottom2',
]);

?>
<script>
let words = <?=json_encode($words)?>;
</script>
```